# Build hardcoded json string from input parameters

Tags: c#

I´m trying to build a hardcoded json string with input parameters in method, but it seems that it doesn´t work. Am I doing wrong here?

```
public string Test(string name, string age) 
{
    string jsonData = @"{
      ""Name"":""' + name +'"",
      ""Age"":""' + age + '""     
    }";

    return jsonData;
}
```

Normally i would use Json.Net but i wonder if there is a way to do it like this. The reason is that i would only use it only in tests and dont want so spend some hours to create objects or anonymous objects to get this json. As someone stated, this is only mocking data.

Comment: "it seems that it doesn't work"? What does that mean? If it doesn't work describe what is happening. I guess there's some syntax error in this (too many quotation signs for me to see what is really going on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you think this (or @cactuaroid's answer) as *correct* one. But it is not. Use @LB's answer...

```
public string Test(string name, string age)
{
    return $@"{{""Name"":""{name}"" , ""Age"":""{age}""}}";
}
```

Just suppose, someone is calling it as `var json = Test("abc\"def", "33");` ==> An invalid json...

---

**EDIT**

Since @LB deleted his answer I'll post it here for future refences.

```
public string Test(string name, string age)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Name = name, Age = age });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, normally i would use JsonConvert, but this is only for testing purposes.

Comment: @L.B Yeah, test in my real project ;)

Comment: @L.B to be fair, perhaps he is mocking some json data that would normally come from some other DLL or external service that has JSON.Net or similar internally and he just needs to create the mock data for unit tests.

Answer (score -1):

Your `jsonData` is just a string, no replacing or anything like that because you specified `@""`. I guess you want something like this.

```
string jsonData = @"{
""Name"":" + name + @""",
""Age"":" + age + @"""
}";
```

Or

```
string jsonData = "{\n" +
"\"Name\":\"" + name + "\",\n" +
"\"Age\":\"" + age + "\"\n" +
"}";
```

Or use `string.Format()`

```
string jsonData = string.Format(@"{{
""Name"":""{0}"",
""Age"":""{1}""
}}", name, age);
```

Or use placeholder.

```
string jsonData = @"{
""Name"":""_name_"",
""Age"":""_age_""
}"
.Replace("_name_", name)
.Replace("_age_", age);
```

Comment: I think you can see the problem of forming a json manually... @Eser has posted an example for it.

Comment: @L.B Yes, totally agree. Usually I also never do this way, but I understand sometimes we want this kind of optimistic loose way.